# JS Countdown timer for website counts from opening of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an html file, and I was working on a countdown timer in the middle of the page which counts down until the site is released.

Screenshot: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4fd8693f6df14261aacb8333ee4a4859.png (I linked it because it's over 2MB)

```
                var targetdate = new Date().getTime() + 2592000000 //Time in milliseconds, in this case it's 1 month. 
                    slidechanges = [
                                { days:0, hours:0, minutes:0, seconds:6, slide:2},
                                { days:0, hours:0, minutes:0, seconds:0, slide:3}
                                    ],
                quickjump = 10000,
                api = revapi432;

            !function(t){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],t):t(jQuery)}(function(t){"use strict";function e(t){if(t instanceof Date)return t;if(String(t).match(o))return String(t).match(/^[0-9]*$/)&&(t=Number(t)),String(t).match(/\-/)&&(t=String(t).replace(/\-/g,"/")),new Date(t);throw new Error("Couldn't cast `"+t+"` to a date object.")}function s(t){var e=t.toString().replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g,"\\$1");return new RegExp(e)}function n(t){return function(e){var n=e.match(/%(-|!)?[A-Z]{1}(:[^;]+;)?/gi);if(n)for(var a=0,o=n.length;o>a;++a){var r=n[a].match(/%(-|!)?([a-zA-Z]{1})(:[^;]+;)?/),l=s(r[0]),c=r[1]||"",u=r[3]||"",f=null;r=r[2],h.hasOwnProperty(r)&&(f=h[r],f=Number(t[f])),null!==f&&("!"===c&&(f=i(u,f)),""===c&&10>f&&(f="0"+f.toString()),e=e.replace(l,f.toString()))}return e=e.replace(/%%/,"%")}}function i(t,e){var s="s",n="";return t&&(t=t.replace(/(:|;|\s)/gi,"").split(/\,/),1===t.length?s=t[0]:(n=t[0],s=t[1])),1===Math.abs(e)?n:s}var a=[],o=[],r={precision:100,elapse:!1};o.push(/^[0-9]*$/.source),o.push(/([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source),o.push(/[0-9]{4}([\/\-][0-9]{1,2}){2}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source),o=new RegExp(o.join("|"));var h={Y:"years",m:"months",n:"daysToMonth",w:"weeks",d:"daysToWeek",D:"totalDays",H:"hours",M:"minutes",S:"seconds"},l=function(e,s,n){this.el=e,this.$el=t(e),this.interval=null,this.offset={},this.options=t.extend({},r),this.instanceNumber=a.length,a.push(this),this.$el.data("countdown-instance",this.instanceNumber),n&&("function"==typeof n?(this.$el.on("update.countdown",n),this.$el.on("stoped.countdown",n),this.$el.on("finish.countdown",n)):this.options=t.extend({},r,n)),this.setFinalDate(s),this.start()};t.extend(l.prototype,{start:function(){null!==this.interval&&clearInterval(this.interval);var t=this;this.update(),this.interval=setInterval(function(){t.update.call(t)},this.options.precision)},stop:function(){clearInterval(this.interval),this.interval=null,this.dispatchEvent("stoped")},toggle:function(){this.interval?this.stop():this.start()},pause:function(){this.stop()},resume:function(){this.start()},remove:function(){this.stop.call(this),a[this.instanceNumber]=null,delete this.$el.data().countdownInstance},setFinalDate:function(t){this.finalDate=e(t)},update:function(){if(0===this.$el.closest("html").length)return void this.remove();var e,s=void 0!==t._data(this.el,"events"),n=new Date;e=this.finalDate.getTime()-n.getTime(),e=Math.ceil(e/1e3),e=!this.options.elapse&&0>e?0:Math.abs(e),this.totalSecsLeft!==e&&s&&(this.totalSecsLeft=e,this.elapsed=n>=this.finalDate,this.offset={seconds:this.totalSecsLeft%60,minutes:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60)%60,hours:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60)%24,days:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24)%7,daysToWeek:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24)%7,daysToMonth:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24%30.4368),totalDays:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24),weeks:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24/7),months:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24/30.4368),years:Math.abs(this.finalDate.getFullYear()-n.getFullYear())},this.options.elapse||0!==this.totalSecsLeft?this.dispatchEvent("update"):(this.stop(),this.dispatchEvent("finish")))},dispatchEvent:function(e){var s=t.Event(e+".countdown");s.finalDate=this.finalDate,s.elapsed=this.elapsed,s.offset=t.extend({},this.offset),s.strftime=n(this.offset),this.$el.trigger(s)}}),t.fn.countdown=function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);return this.each(function(){var s=t(this).data("countdown-instance");if(void 0!==s){var n=a[s],i=e[0];l.prototype.hasOwnProperty(i)?n[i].apply(n,e.slice(1)):null===String(i).match(/^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i)?(n.setFinalDate.call(n,i),n.start()):t.error("Method %s does not exist on jQuery.countdown".replace(/\%s/gi,i))}else new l(this,e[0],e[1])})}});


            var currentd,currenth,currentm,currents;

            function animateAndUpdate(o,nt,ot) {
               if (ot==undefined) {
                 o.html(nt);
               } else {
                  if (o.css("opacity")>0) {
                  punchgs.TweenLite.fromTo(o,0.45,
                    {autoAlpha:1,rotationY:0,scale:1},
                    {autoAlpha:0,rotationY:-180,scale:0.5,ease:punchgs.Back.easeIn,onComplete:function() { o.html(nt);} });

              punchgs.TweenLite.fromTo(o,0.45,
                    {autoAlpha:0,rotationY:180,scale:0.5},
                    {autoAlpha:1,rotationY:0,scale:1,ease:punchgs.Back.easeOut,delay:0.5 });
                  } else {
                     o.html(nt);
                  }
               }
              return nt;
            }

            function countprocess(event) {

              var newd = event.strftime('%D'),
                  newh = event.strftime('%H'),
                  newm = event.strftime('%M'),
                  news = event.strftime('%S');
              if (newd != currentd) currentd = animateAndUpdate(jQuery('#c_days'),newd,currentd);
              if (newh != currenth) currenth = animateAndUpdate(jQuery('#c_hours'),newh,currenth);
              if (newm != currentm) currentm = animateAndUpdate(jQuery('#c_minutes'),newm,currentm);
              if (news != currents) currents = animateAndUpdate(jQuery('#c_seconds'),news,currents);

              jQuery.each(slidechanges,function(i,obj) {
                var dr = obj.days==undefined || obj.days>=newd,
                    hr = obj.hours==undefined || obj.hours>=newh,
                    mr = obj.minutes==undefined || obj.minutes>=newm,
                    sr = obj.seconds==undefined || obj.seconds>=news;
                  if (dr && hr && mr && sr && !obj.changedown) {
                     api.revshowslide(obj.slide);
                     obj.changedown = true;
                  }
              })
            }

            jQuery('#skipahead').click(function(){
              var smalloffset = new Date().getTime() + quickjump;
             api.countdown(smalloffset,countprocess);
            });

            api.countdown(targetdate, countprocess);
        }
    }); /*ready*/
```

Now my issue here is, that the counter starts counting down from 30 days when the page gets loaded.
Is there a way to get the first string (since that's the issue here I think) to act as a custom date setting where I can choose when it starts counting, or better if possible where it counts to a point?

The page is very close bound to this code, a wrong value stops the page from loading at all and the counter handles various events on the page, which, I would like to keep.

The Countdown.js jQuery Engine is made by hilios.
Page of the code is at: https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown

Thanks for all the help I get,

Frozen Snow

Comment: The demos of that plugin show you what you need to do...set  an absolute target date

Comment: The image is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

`var targetdate = new Date().getTime() + 2592000000`

to this:

`var targetdate = new Date(2016, 7, 1, 5, 30, 0) // change the values to correspond with the date you want`

This will set the target date to Monday August 1st, at 5:30.

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for more info on creating dates.

Comment: It seems I can't publicly upvote your comment, but that fixed it!

Comment: @frozen you should be able to mark the answer as the correct one. But it doesn't really matter always glad to help.